# Delete file after "x" second after creation

Tags: vb.net, function

I want to delete file after 15 second of create that file.
I use this code but no success.

```
Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
Dim test = Application.StartupPath & "\" + tte4
Timer1.Enabled = True
        If Timer1.Interval = 0 Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(test)
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "no success" - means what exactly?  the file doesn't delete?  You get an exeption?

Comment: A timer raises an event. You need to handle it there. You seem to be using it like it blocks until the timer elapsed.

Comment: It mean file doesn't delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must handle the timed event in a handler for the Timer's Tick Event (or Elapsed if using System.Timers.Timer):

```
Private m_strTest As String = String.Empty

Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click

    m_strTest = Application.StartupPath & "\" + tte4
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

If using System.Forms.Timer (most likely):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    System.IO.File.Delete(m_strTest)    
    Timer1.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

If using System.Timers.Timer:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Elapsed(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Timer1_Elapsed

    System.IO.File.Delete(m_strTest)
    Timer1.Stop()

End Sub
```

If you added your Timer from the Toolbox, the above code will work (due to WithEvents).  If you added it programatically, you'll also have to wire up the Event Handler and remove the Handles from your Timer1_Tick Method:

```
Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click

    m_strTest = Application.StartupPath & "\" + tte4

    AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick

    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    System.IO.File.Delete(m_strTest)    
    Timer1.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need define a method that the timer fires when the interval elapses.

```
' Timer set to fire every 15 seconds
Dim Timer1 As New Timer(15000)
' OnTimedEvent is the method that will fire after 15 seconds
AddHandler Timer1.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
' Start the Timer
Timer1.Start()
```

The OnTimedEvent is as followed:

```
Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    ' Stop the timer from firing again
    Timer1.Stop()

    ' Delete your file
End Sub
```

Reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0wdddfy(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea in using a Timer to wait for the deletion, but your way of trying to use it is incorrect. A (System.Windows.Forms) Timer raises an event when it ticks, and you need to tie that event to the code you want to run.

Also, to combine parts of a path it is better to use [IO.Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and when doing file operations it is a good idea to "wrap" the relevant code in a [Try..Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) construct *and* handle the exception if it happens.

So:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim tim1 As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Dim tte4 As String = "afile.txt"

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        tim1.Enabled = False
        Dim target = Path.Combine("C:\temp", tte4)

        If File.Exists(target) Then
            Try
                File.Delete(target)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The file ""{0}"" could not be deleted because {1}", target, ex.Message))
            End Try
        Else
            ' the file does not exist - do something if required
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub SetUpTimer()
        tim1.Enabled = False
        tim1.Interval = 1000 * 15
        ' here we tie the event to the code
        AddHandler tim1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
        ' this has the side-effect of trying to delete a file after an interval
        tim1.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetUpTimer()

    End Sub

End Class
```

You did not show code for creating the file - I assume you used a click on the form just to demonstrate the idea.